# Android sharedpreferences get cleared after device RAM goes up

Tags: android, sqlite, memory, sharedpreferences, ram

I have an android app and i used to store login status inside **shredPreferences**.I tried with both **editor.apply();** and **editor.commit();** for save changes to shared.But when the RAM goes up my app crashes and sharedPreferences get cleared.I used to test the RAM issue by using **fill RAM memory** app in playstore.Should i use SQLITE instead of sharedPreferences? will i gonna face same issue for SQLITE?

Comment: I don't see why a lack of RAM would cause items on the storage device to be deleted. It seems likely you've misdiagnosed the problem. Perhaps you could attempt to reproduce the behavior with an MVCE.

Comment: Start with fixing the crash.

Comment: Try with simple test app, store some value in sharedPreferences and use fill RAM memory app to test, increase the RAM until app gets crash, then check the shared value,